# regex extract data from raw text

Tags: python, regex, extract

I work in hotel. here is raw file from rapports i have.I need to extract data in order to have something like `data['roomNumber']=('paxNumber',isbb,)`

Here is a sample that concern only 2 room, the 10 and 12 so the data i need should be `BreakfastData = {'10':['2','BB'],'12':['1','BB']}`

1)roomNumber : 'start and ends with number' or 'start with number and strictly one or more space followd by string'
  2)paxNumber are the two numbers just before the 'VA' string
  3)isbb is defined by the 'BB' or 'HPDJ' occurrence which can be find between two '/'. But sometimes the format is not good so it can be '/HPDJ/' or '/ HPDJ /' or '/ HPDJ/' etc

> 10 PxxxxD,David,Mme, Mr T- EXPEDIA TRAVEL
>
> 08.05.17 12.05.17 TP
>
> SUP DBL / HPDJ / DEBIT CB AGENCE - NR
>
> 2 0 VA
>
> NR
>
> 12
>
> LxxxxSH,Claudia,Mrs
>
> 08.05.17 19.05.17 TP
>
> 1 0 VA
>
> NR BB
>
> SUP SGL / BB / EN ATTENTE DE VIREMENT- EVITER LA 66 -
>
> .... etc

edit :latest

```
import re
data = {}
pax=''
r = re.compile(r"(\d+)\W*(\d+)\W*VA")
r2 = re.compile(r"/\s*(BB|HPDJ)\s*/")
r3 = re.compile(r"\d+\n")
r4 = re.compile(r"\d+\s+\w")
PATH = "/home/ryms/regextest"

with open(PATH, 'rb') as raw:
    text=raw.read()
#roomNumber = re.search(r4, text).group()
#roomNumber2 = re.search(r3, text).group()
roomNumber = re.search(r4, text).group().split()[0]
roomNumber2 = re.search(r3, text).group().split()[0]

pax = re.findall(r, text)
adult = pax[0]; enfant = pax[1]
# if enfant is '0':
#   pax=adult
# else:
#   pax=(str(adult)+'+'+str(enfant))
bb = re.findall(r2, text)       #On recherche BB ou HPDJ
data[roomNumber]=pax,bb

print(data)
print(roomNumber)
print(roomNumber2)
```

return

```
{'10': ([('2', '2'), ('1', '1')], ['HPDJ', 'BB'])}
10
12
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

How can i get the two roomNumber in my return?
I have lot of trouble with the \n issue and read(), readline(), readlines().what is the trick?

When i will have all raw data, how will i get the proper BreakfastData{}? will  i use .zip()?
At the bigining i wanted to split the file and then parse it , but i try so may things, i get lost. And for that i need a regex that match both pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first case you want to select two numbers which are followed by 'VA' you can do like this

```
 r = re.compile(r"(\d+)\W*(\d+)\W*VA")
```

In second case you can get HPDJ or BB like this

```
r = re.compile(r"/\s*(HPDJ|BB)\s*/")
```

this will handle all cases you mentioned >>  /HPDJ/' or '/ HPDJ /' or '/ HPDJ/'

Comment: these two expressions will be match in your case

        1) ^\d+$   #this will match 'start and ends with number'

        2) ^\d+\s+\w+$  # this will match 'start with number and strictly one or more space followd by string'

Comment: can i make one regex with the two? i dont see a use of re.findall with multiple pattern? .. And how can i get only the numbers not the \n or the 'P'

Comment: Do not ask these much questions in comments. ask new questions for new doubts and accept current answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression to get the text before the VA is as follows:

```
r = re.compile(r"(.*) VA")
```

Then the "number" (which will be a string) will be stored in the first `group` of the search match object, once you run the search.

I am not quite sure what the room number even is, because your description is a bit unclear, so I cannot help with that unless you clarify.